# How to create a common interface for various implementations?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I'm doing small exercise project to have more practice with programming in general.
The project is a program that takes content of CSV file and puts it in some database.
I started from creating a database-access interface `IDatabaseClient`, which made me think about a few things:

1. How should my `Connect(...)` method look like? Various databases might have a different set of credentials that are needed for connection, i.e. one might need a conenction string, another might need: URL, username, password, etc. One way to solve this could be to have `Connect` method like this:

Task Connect(IConnectionCredentials credentials);

`IConnectionCredentials` interface would be empty and each database would have its own implementation of it, like this for example:

```
public class DatabaseNo1Credentials : IConnectionCredentials
{
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The thing that I don't like about such solution is that the user of `IDatabaseClient` implementation does not have any information which credentials class should be used. The code will throw an exception if wrong credentials class is provided. Is there a better solution?

2. My CSV files could contain data for different database tables. One CSV could contain Cars data, another could contain People data, etc. How do I make my `IDatabaseClient` usable for many kids of data?

I could do this:

```
public interface IDatabaseClient
{
    Task Connect(IConnectionCredentials credentials);
    Task WriteCars(string model, int productionYear);
    Task WritePeople(string firstName, string lastName, int age);
}
```

However, what if one day I want to write data to Phones table, or any other table?

Comment: Can you only ask one question at a time?

Comment: @Sweeper My question is generally about designing good interfaces. I gave 2 examples of why I think my interface is not perfect. No need to split it into 2 questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface is too specific, in terms of methods and especially in terms of method parameters.
You should not have a `Connect` method with parameters, rather you would do something like this:

```
interface IDatabaseClient
{
    Task ConnectAsync();

    Task AddDataAsync<T>(string databaseName, T data);
}

class DatabaseClient1 : IDatabaseClient
{
    public DatabaseClient1(string username, string password)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    public string Username { get;  }

    public string Password { get;  }

    public async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        // connect using Username and Password
    }

    public async Task AddDataAsync<T>(string databaseName, T data)
    {
        // Not sure if you can work with a generic method for inserting data
        // into your database, but given that you didn't specify your 
        // requirements further, I'm just going to go with this
    }
}
```

Having multiple database table specific operations in one interface defeats the purpose of having an interface in my opinion, so you should delegate the specific work to other classes, which only depend on the IDatabaseClient:

```
class CarManager
{
    public CarManager(IDatabaseClient databaseClient)
    {
        _databaseClient = databaseClient;
    }

    public async Task AddCarAsync(string model, int productionYear)
    {
        var car = new Car(model, productionYear);

        _databaseClient.AddDataAsync("cars", car);
    }

    private readonly IDatabaseClient _databaseClient;
}
```